# How to generate variable names from sequences

Tags: macros, errors, expl3, l3seq

In my code it's need for me generate variables from sequences. For example, I have variable `\g__test_bool`. For an empty sequence it should be the same. For sequence with `a_` item it should be `\g__test_a_bool`, for sequence with `a_,b_` items it should be `\g__test_a_b_bool`, etc. But when I try to do this, I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \g__
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N\g__vars_seq
\bool_gset_true:N\g__test_bool
\bool_if:NTF\g__\seq_use:Nn\g__vars_seq{}test_bool{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are building the control sequence name from a string of characters, you need to use the `c` variant, `\bool_if:cTF`, otherwise the control sequence is `\g__`, which does not exist.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g__kozlovskiy_vars_seq
\bool_gset_true:N \g__kozlovskiy_test_bool

\bool_if:cTF
  { g__kozlovskiy_ \seq_use:Nn \g__kozlovskiy_vars_seq { } test_bool }
  { \typeout{TRUE} }
  { \typeout{FALSE} }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```